# how to select photo from table in database based on employee id in plsql dynamic content using htp.p in oracle apex?

Tags: plsql, printing, oracle-apex

I have an app that used to registrate events.the user can see his events only,some of these events has badge . the user want to see his badge and dowload it as pdf.
i have designed the badge using plsql dynamic content region.
the padge consist of header,body and footer, the body must have user picture,user name,event name and event date.
I could display all the data except the picture.
can anyone help me to display the user picture based on the user id and event id?

I tried to do that using static file under shared components this way was successful with one by one.
I want all the data including picture to change based on user id and event id.

Answer (score 0):

Using `HTP.P` you'll need `UTL_ENCODE.BASE64_ENCODE`

something like

```
htp.p('<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' || UTL_ENCODE.BASE64_ENCODE(l_photo) || '" alt="Employee Photo">');
```

but I recommend using the Media/Resource from RESTful Services which is much easier and reusable.